# Xamarin Forms changing the size of a viewcell dynamically

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Using a Xamarin Forms ListView with a custom ViewCell, is it possible to have a list item expand based on an event?  Please ignore the orange lines, but reference the below picture...

[image]

1. Regular cell not expanded
2. User has tapped the triple dots causing the ViewCell to expand to show additional content

Is this possible?  What is the technique to make that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have containers or elements inside your viewcell whose Visibility can be controlled based on the click. You will have to re render the elements once its expanded or collapsed for the viewcell to resize. Or else  you will have the Viewcell being the size it was initially rendered, but the contents inside it overflowing.

Check out the following links :

1. [How to implement Expandable/Collapsible ListView in xamarin forms?](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/33975/how-to-implement-expandable-collapsible-listview-in-xamarin-forms)
2. [CollapseListView-in-xamarin.forms](https://github.com/shuklajay/CollapseListView-in-xamarin.forms)
3. [ExpandableListView](https://github.com/away168/ExpandableListView)

Comment: Please go through the samples.